# Equivalent of \nocite{} for \mcite{} in biblatex?

Tags: biblatex

What is the `\mcite{}` equivalent for `\nocite{}` in `biblatex`?

## Background

I am trying to reproduce a set of reference in another document using `biblatex`.  The other document uses the equivalent of `\mcite{}` in several places, concatenating reference.  My current solution is to reproduce the reference structure with something like:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber, bibstyle=numeric, mcite, ]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{tst.bib}

\begin{document}
\mcite{set1, *Ref1:2008, *Ref2:2009}  % What is the \nocite{} equivalence?
\nocite{Ref3:2013}
\section*{References}
\printbibliography[heading=none]
\end{document}
```

(here is the bibliography file `tst.bib`)

```
@Article{Ref1:2008,
  author =       {Author A},
  title =        {Title A},
  journal =      {A Journal},
  year =         {2008},
}
@Article{Ref2:2009,
  author =       {Author B},
  title =        {Title B},
  journal =      {A Journal},
  year =         {2009},
}
@Article{Ref3:2013,
  author =       {Author D},
  title =        {Title D},
  journal =      {A Journal},
  year =         {20013},
}
```

[image: Sample output]

I can of course hack this so all the citations appear on the first page and then chop that off, but there seems to be an asymmetry and that a `\nomcite` command should exist.

Comment: Sorry but I don't really understand what `\nomcite` would do? Why can't you just use `\nocite` if you want the references in the list of references without anything appearing in the text itself? I guess I'm not clear what aspect of `\nocite` you want to combine with what aspect of `\mcite`.

Comment: @cfr The aspect of ``\mcite`` I want is to have a group of papers combined into a single bibliographic reference, but without a citation in the text.  ``\nocite`` would add each reference as a separate citation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In `biblatex` you can group references using `@set` in a `bib` file or you can dynamically create an entry set with `\definebibentryset`. Thus you can obtain the desired effect by

```
\defbibentryset{set1}{Ref1:2008,Ref2:2009}
```

Adding the above line to the provided MWE produces:

[image]

Comment: This seems almost like the right answer, but the ``\nocite{set1}`` is not required (``\defbibentryset{}`` implicitly behaves as a ``\nocite``).  However, it does beg the question: what is the purpose of the ``\mcite`` command then?  Is it just a shortcut for this with a similar signature to aid backward compatibility, or is there some other advantage to using it?

Comment: Reading the docs a bit more closely it indeed says that ``\mcite{}`` is essentially equivalent to a compact form of ``\defbibentryset{}`` so it seems best to use the latter in general as it is more explicit and allows one to emulate the desired ``\nomcite{}`` behaviour.

Comment: @mforbes If you use BibTeX, you have to pre-define everything as at present the code is not set up to do this 'dynamically': `\defbibentryset` only works with Biber.

Comment: @JosephWright The ``\mcite{}`` command seems to also have the Biber-only limitation, so I guess this is still the best answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can place multiple identifiers in the `\nocite` command.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
    @Article{Ref1:2008,
      author =       {Author A},
      title =        {Title A},
      journal =      {A Journal},
      year =         {2008},
    }
    @Article{Ref2:2009,
      author =       {Author B},
      title =        {Title B},
      journal =      {A Journal},
      year =         {2009},
    }
    @Article{Ref3:2013,
      author =       {Author D},
      title =        {Title D},
      journal =      {A Journal},
      year =         {20013},
    }
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[backend=biber, bibstyle=numeric, mcite, ]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{Ref1:2008,Ref2:2009}
\section*{References}
\printbibliography[heading=none]
\end{document}
```

Comment: I need to keep the numbering the same as in the original document, so the two references need to be grouped under a single number which is what ``\mcite{}`` does.  Using ``\nocite{}`` combines the two entries at the point of citation, but not in the reference section where two seperate numbers are issues.